# Why can't the lifetimes be inferred in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following example

```rust
struct Foo {
    val: &str
}

fn main() {
    let hello = String::from("hello");
    let foo = Foo{ val: &hello[..]};

}
```

This doesn't compile because a lifetime is required. A very simple fix would be the following:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    val: &'a str
}
```

Why can't the compiler assume (as a sensible default) that the reference will live as long as the struct `Foo` ? Are there any use cases where this would not be the case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because assuming reference will live as long as the `struct Foo` would be plain wrong. Consider this for example.

```
fn main() {
    let foo: Foo;
    {
        let string = "foo".to_string();
        foo = Foo {
            val: string.as_str(),
        }
    }

    println!("{}", foo.val);


}
```

If compiler had assumed the "sensible default" here that `string` will live as long as `Foo`, this would compile . But we can clearly see that `string` will be dropped after inner loop ends but `foo` will live even after it.

In short, its `Foo`'s lifetime that is dependent on the `&str` and not the other way around, i.e. `Foo` cannot outlive `&str`.

Comment: This is a bit hard to track, but no: if the compiler would assume that, this _wouldn't_ compile, because the string _does not_ live as long as the `Foo`.